# Grant create permission on a specific schema in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, security

I have two users A and B. I want to grant B the permission to create, drop, etc. all tables in A's schema. As far as I can see, I can grant B full access to all schemas not a specific one. Is this correct?

Answer (score 11):

You are correct that there is no way to grant a user create/drop/etc permissions on an entire schema.  I suggest you look into [proxy authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authentication.htm#DBSEG33101).  This basically involves altering user A to allow user B to proxy as A:

```
ALTER USER A GRANT CONNECT THROUGH B;
```

Then the connection uses user B's authentication, but gets the permissions of user A.

```
connect B[A]/Password@Database
```

This question was somewhat covered by my more specific question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/305/security-for-application-developers-doing-pl-sql-work-in-oracle).

---

Note on Roles: Roles work well for giving *Object Privileges* to another user since the privileges are tied to a specific object.  While Roles can grant *System Privileges*, they apply either to the users own schema or to the entire database and therefore can't apply to another schema.  For example, the user B could be granted `CREATE TABLE` which would allow it to create tables in its own schema or `CREATE ANY TABLE` which would allow it to create tables in any schema.  These permissions could be granted directly or through a role, but the former wouldn't allow create privileges in the A schema.  The latter would, but would also allow create privileges in any schema including sys, which would be a security concern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a pity of course. Basically, I don't understand why such a simple feature is not available in Oracle.

Comment: Just found this feature on a 12c wish list: http://www.dadbm.com/2012/03/oracle-database-12c-wish-list/

Comment: I would highly prefer to decouple users from schemas. Just like in MySQL.

Comment: The permission would have to exist for the decoupling to work, so perhaps it would be a first step in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a procedure on the target schema which involves EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE to create tables (check for other DDLs!!). Then grant the source schema privilege to execute on procedure. This should do the trick without security concerns.

Answer (score -1):

You could just create a role with those permissions, and grant the role to whoever needs that ability.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? Leigh said that I cannot grant on an specfic entire schema.

Comment: A Role can only include permissions that can be granted directly. The user B could be granted `CREATE TABLE` which would allow it to create tables in its own schema or `CREATE ANY TABLE` which would allow it to create tables in any schema.  These permissions could be granted directly or through a role, but the first is too narrow and the second too broad.

Comment: Leigh, exactly, none fits.