# Oracle: what permission is necessary to "grant create table" to another user?

Tags: oracle, permissions

What permission should `A` have in order to grant `B` permission to create a table?

logged in as user `A`, I execute

```
grant create table to B;
```

and receive the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
           without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
           attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
           system privileges.
           When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur
           if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label
           than the current login.
*Action:   Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or grant
           the required privileges.
           For Trusted Oracle users getting this error although granted the
           the appropriate privilege at a higher label, ask the database
           administrator to regrant the privilege at the appropriate label.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to grant permissions one schema to another schema.  Such a thing does not exist in Oracle, but [there are workarounds](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13320/grant-create-permission-on-a-specific-schema-in-oracle-11g).

The easiest way to make this happen is to grant the CREATE ANY TABLE privilege to B, but there are obvious security concerns with doing so.

Comment: Thanks Leigh, the referenced workaround does just what I need.